# Почему нужно использовать void? А не int?

Tags: java, методы

прощу не ругаться за глупые вопросы, начал изучать программирование и при решение задачи, возник вопрос, почему нужно использовать void, а не int в методе setSize. При использовании int компилятор выдает ошибку.

```
class GoodDog{
    private int size;

public int getSize(){
    return size;
}
**public void setSize(int s){**
    size=s;
}

    void bark(int times){
        while(times>0){
        if(size>40){
            System.out.println(" GAAAAAV");
        }
        else if(size>14){
            System.out.println(" WUUUF");
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("TYF");
        }
        times--;
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Модификатор **void** означает, что функция не возвращает никакого значения. Другими словами, при возвращении управления в точку, откуда функция была вызвана, в стеке не сохранится никакое значение.

```
public int getSize();
```

Например, функция выше возвращает значение типа **int**, это значит, что мы можем получить какое-то значение при завершении работы функции и присвоить какой-нибудь переменной типа **int**, например:

```
GoodDog dog = new GoodDog();
int dogSize = dog.getSize();
```

И наоборот, методы void часто используются для установки какого-нибудь значения, в вашем примере это метод setSize(), например:

```
dog.setSize(2);
```

> При использовании int компилятор выдает ошибку.

Потому что в конце функции нужен оператор **return**, который указывает компилятору, что нужно прекратить работу функции и какое значение нужно возвратить.

*Замечание.* При достижении оператора **return** функция сразу прекращает свою работу и возвращает указанное значение, независимо от того, где он находится. Также в методах с возвращаемым типом **void** можно явно указать, когда нужно прекратить работу функции с помощью следующего синтаксиса:

```
void foo() {
  if (x > 0)
    return;
  else {
    ...
  }
}
```

В данном случае, так как у функции `foo()` возвращаемый тип void, при достижении оператора return она вернет управление в точку, откуда была вызвана, и не вернет никакого значения.

Comment: Другими словами метод int getSize() станет как будто переменной?

Comment: Нет, он всегда был методом и им останется. Просто он будет **возвращать** значение типа int в точку, откуда был вызван. Вот например, можно даже написать:
`GoodDog dog = new GoodDog();`
`dog.setSize(3);`
`dog.getSize();`
В этом случае метод getSize() отработает в штатном режиме, но его значение не присвоится никакой переменнной.

Comment: не присвоит значение потому, что он был запущен после метода setSize()?

Comment: Смотрите: когда мы **просто вызываем** метод `getSize()` и не присваиваем **результат его работы** никакой переменной, то есть: `dog.getSize();`, то он конечно занесет значение `size` в стек (то есть вернет, от англ. return - "возвращать"), однако это значение **не присвоится никакой переменной**. Только если мы напишем `int size = dog.getSize();`, то тогда переменная `size` будет сохранять значение `size` объекта `dog` класса `GoodDog`.

Comment: Может так будет понятней: оператор `return` нужен для получения **результата работы** функции.

Comment: Спасибо большое вроде понял:) Блин мне нравится этот сайт, задал два вопроса и сразу получил на них ответы с пояснениями. Спасибо еще раз:)

Comment: Пожалуйста. Вот еще житейское объяснение.) Начальник сказал вам выполнить некоторую работу. В данном случае начальник - это **программист**, а вы - это **метод**. Если вы `void`-метод, то вы выполните эту работу и **не вернете** начальнику отчет. Однако если вы метод с возвращаемым типом, отличным от `void`, то вы **вернете** начальнику отчет о проделанной работе. Этот отчет и есть значение, возвращаемое оператором `return`. Далее начальник поступает как ему хочется: кладет отчет на полку (как программист заносит это значение в переменную) или выбрасывает отчет (то есть не присваивает...

Comment: ...результат работы метода какой-нибудь переменной). Надеюсь, аналогия понятна)

Comment: вот сейчас точно понятно:) Вы сделали мой день добрый человек:) Спасибо большое:)

Comment: Да пожалуйста) Только вот "выбрасывать отчет" не рекомендуется. Лучше использовать `void`.

Comment: так точно, буду знать:)

Comment: @bazmexes чувак книги читай и не задавай глупых вопросов

Comment: @Санаев книга читается, если не нравится вопросы просто пропускай мимо.

Answer (score 1):

> почему нужно использовать void, а не int в методе setSize.

Метод ничего **не возвращает**, т.е. нет слова `return`. Да, **присваивает**, но **не возвращает**. На это и указывает слово `void`